# JQuery UI Widget / Plugin: CamelCase the namespace and/or plugin name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When creating a jQuery UI widget is it possible to make the namespace and / or plugin name CamelCase or is the convention all lowercase.. spaces replaced with underscores?

Just wondering about both possiblity and convention.

Comment: It is possible to use whatever convention you want, it's just a name. You can even use spaces, however you would be limited to using bracket syntax to call it. I suggest using camelCase (note the lowercase first letter and all spaces/dashes removed)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Not sure if you want to put that as an answer instead of a comment, but it works for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use whatever convention you want, it's just a name. You can even use spaces, however you would be limited to using bracket syntax to call it. I suggest using camelCase (note the lowercase first letter and all spaces/dashes removed)

```
$(sel).myPlugin()
$(sel).MyPlugin()
$(sel).MYPLUGIN()
$(sel).MyPlUgIn()
$(sel)["My Superawsome Fantastic Plugin"]()
```